# « En » ou « les » dans « Est-il possible d'en / de les livrer le dimanche ? »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Il y a une phrase dans une lettre

> Est-ce qu'il est possible de livrer des livres le dimanche?

J'aimerais remplacer *des livres*. Ma pensée est utiliser le pronom **en**

> Est-ce qu'il est possible d'**en** livrer le dimanche?

Ou faut-il utiliser **les** ?

> Est-ce qu'il est possible de **les** livrer le dimanche?

Comment: C'est en effet **en** qu'il faut utiliser ici. **les** serait utilisé pour parler de livres précis (ex: "As-tu reçu les livres de la collection tartenpion ? Peux-tu me **les** livrer ?")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

S'il s'agit d'une question sur la possibilité, en général, de livrer des livres le dimanche : « d'en livrer le dimanche ».

S'il s'agit d'une livraison particulière : « de les livrer le dimanche ».

La phrase « Est-ce qu'il est possible de livrer des livres le dimanche ? » ne permet pas de déterminer s'il s'agit du premier ou du second cas.

Comment: Pour la deuxième solution, la phrase d'origine serait plutôt "Est-ce qu'il est possible de livrer **les** livres le dimanche ?" non ?

Comment: Elle aurait pu l'être, mais pas nécessairement. « Livrer des livres » peut aussi bien signifier « livrer des livres en général » ou « livrer des livres en particulier », c'est à dire que le « des » peut être indéfini ou partitif.

Comment: @jilliagre: Dans les deux cas (partitif ou indéfini) le pronom équivalent c'est *en*. *Tu veux du sel ? Tu en veux ? ; Tu veux un livre ? Tu en veux un ? ; Tu veux des livres ? Tu en veux ?*. À comparer avec *Tu veux les livres ? Tu les veux ?*

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez On dira *Je viens t'apporter des livres pour ton fils, tu les veux ?* plutôt que *Je viens t'apporter des livres pour ton fils, tu en veux ?*

Comment: Qui correspond à *Je viens t'apporter des livres pour ton fils, tu veux les livres ?*. C'est un nom introduit par un article défini que tu remplaces par *les*.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un contexte précis, la seconde proposition me semble plus adéquate, à savoir:

> Est-ce qu'il est possible de **les** livrer le dimanche?

Le souci avec la première proposition utilisant le pronom personnel **en** réside dans le fait que celui-ci fait référence à une quantité non spécifiée.

Une troisième alternative:

> Est-ce qu'il est possible de livrer **ces derniers** le dimanche?

Comment: "Ces derniers" n'est utilisé qu'à l'écrit, par contre.

Comment: C'est exact. La personne ayant postée la question à fait mention d'une lettre, raison pour laquelle j'ai proposé cette troisième option.

Comment: "livrer des livres" ne spécifie pas de quantité précise non plus, donc où est le problème avec "en" ?

Answer (score 1):

***"livrer des livres"*** correspond à ***"en** livrer", car "**des**" est un pluriel indéterminé, qui ne présume pas d'une quantité finie. En anglais, on dirait "***to deliver (some) books***".

***"livrer les livres"*** correspond à *"**les** livrer",* car "**les**" est un pluriel défini: l'ensemble des livres est ici fermé, déterminé. En anglais, cela correspondrait à "**to deliver (all) the books**".